# expl3 conflicts with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

When I use `expl3` with `tikz` errors are raised (pdflatex). My complete code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can see the effect [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zgfcndghrcmt). I notice that using xelatex the code in the link compiles correctly. Nevertheless it sometimes still functions badly.

What is the method to have them work better together?

Comment: Please cite the error you get. Just visiting the link you provided compiles without error on overleaf for me

Comment: See [Workaround how to use expl3 functionality in tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197083/workaround-how-to-use-expl3-functionality-in-tikz) and linked questions.

Comment: That having said in this particular example just move `\ExplSyntaxOn` after `\begin{document}` can fix.

Comment: There is no reason to do `\ExplSyntaxOn` just before `\begin{document}` and several for not doing it.

Comment: remove explsyntaxon it is doing nothing useful in that position. if you did have some expl3 code in the preamble follow it by \ExplSyntaxOff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing `\begin{document}` under the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` is a very bad idea, sorry.

Several packages delay loading configuration files at begin document and inputting a file under the `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime is, to say the least, risky: spaces and endlines are ignored and if a file does

```
\mycountera=100
\ifnum\mycounterb=\mycountera 10\else 0\fi
```

(made up code to show one of the possible issues) you'd end with `\mycountera` holding the value 10010 or 1000, depending on the current value of `\mycounterb`. The given code is valid and would set `\mycountera` to 100 when spaces aren't ignored, then print 10 or 0. But when spaces are ignored, the `\ifnum` is expanded prior to TeX having determined the value passed to `\mycountera`.

Think to `\ExplSyntaxOn` as bringing an aircraft to the hangar for installation of new equipment. You want to end the installation before pulling the aircraft on the runway for take-off, don't you?

When you're under `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime, never do typesetting. Well, sometimes

```
\ExplSyntaxOn<expl3 code>\ExplSyntaxOff
```

might be appealing inside `document`. Avoid it and define prior to `\begin{document}` a user level command doing the business: install the equipment first, then take-off.

David's answer to [Checking whether an item of a string is space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669458/4427) is a case: his usage of `\ExplSyntaxOn` inside `document` was just by way of example, but not aimed to be what you'd do in a real document.